# How to get group 1 and group 2 in the regex

Tags: regex

I have the following string **LEFT-ARC-det** which I would like to have two matching groups in regexp:

I tried this:

```
.*-([^-]*)
```

But it is matching only **det** as group 1, [see here](https://regex101.com/r/P5fGjW/1/)

I would like to have:

```
Full match    LEFT-ARC-det
Group 1.      LEFT-ARC
Group 2.      det
```

Any clue?

Comment: You only have 1 group, you don't have 2.

Comment: i want to be able to select the matching groups separately in python. As both are useful.

Comment: Why don't you just add another group ?

Comment: Doing as per Neil. Works :)

Comment: Why didn't you do it to begin with ?

Comment: Still beginner in regex. Didn't realize the mistake.

Comment: Writing regex is like writing a template. If you want substrings separate you add groups. Can be nested, doesn't matter. Since you have a group already, I thought you'd have known this.

Comment: Thanks for these explanations. It helps me improve!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only have one capturing group, `([^-]*)`, which will only get `det` because `.*-` matches everything before it. You just need to capture the first part in a group as well.

`(.*)-([^-]*)`